# How to deserialize datetime to local time?

Tags: c#, .net-core, deserialization

I know dates should be stored in UTC Time and then be displayed based on client's configuration using libraries such as "moment-timezone". However, I'm writing software for a huge organization with a lot of legacy systems. It's not their culture storing dates as UTC. They have dozens of databases and thousands of tables, none uses UTC.

My Angular application sends data to my API as ISO format. My controllers receives date with the property `Kind` equals `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

I'm able to convert date to local time like this:

```
    public  static class DateTimeExtension
    {
        public static DateTime ToBrasiliaTime(this DateTime date)
        {
            if (date.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc)
                return date;

            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time"));
        }
    }
```

I could then use

```
customer.bithrDate = customer.bithrDate.ToBrasiliaTime();....
product.assemblyDate = product.assemblyDate .ToBrasiliaTime();....
order.shippingDate = order.shippingDate .ToBrasiliaTime();....
```

But I don't want to call this extension all over and over... Is it possible to implement a Model Binder to deal with body data and apply my extension logic?

Again, I know dates should be stored in UTC Time, but that's not the point.

Comment: Just to clarify, is your client sending json? And you want to deserialize the data as it comes into the API straight to your class/model?

Comment: There are two basic approaches to centralizing this. If you're receiving the data as JSON, as @haldo asks, you could setup a [custom JSON converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#sample-basic-converter) for `DateTime` types. Alternatively, yes, you can create a [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-model-binder-sample) that apply to your action parameters or to binding model properties using a `ModelBinderProvider`.

Comment: Converting time is pretty easy to do. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: Also, DateTime converts UTC to local time by default when parsing, or at least that’s how it used to behave (was poor behavior in my opinion, but you may find that useful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a **Newtonsoft.Json** solution using a custom JSON converter.  This assumes your date is sent as UTC.

```
public class LocalDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null)
        {
            return null; // or DateTime.MinValue since its automatically converted anyway
        }  

        var date = DateTime.Parse(reader.Value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time"));
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true; 
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

Decorate the `DateTime` property in your model with the `JsonConverter` attribute.  It would look something like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(LocalDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

Even though the converter returns null when a null value is passed in, this method will still result in `DateTime.MinValue` when it's converted to a `DateTime`.  You'd need to change the type to nullable `DateTime?` if you actually want null instead.

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PmrCif)

Comment: I was looking for a very generic solution, for example, I didn't want to specify the Converter or ModelBinder for each property or each model. I was also looking for something like this https://dev.to/usmanuzi/how-to-bind-model-value-frombody-by-custom-binder-in-asp-net-core-32ik - however I had to specify the ModelBinder for each class. For now, I applied your solution and it's working.